# What are these round, white, waxy things on my cycad?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, pest-control, indoors, insects

What are these white things on this cycad? Are they some kind of bugs, or are they seeds?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In a pot, use potting soil, not regular soil. There is far too much water in that crock also. It should have drainage holes. Pests like scale avoid plants that are at their healthiest, so improving conditions will help the plant stay pest-free.

Answer (score 2):

That picture is of a [cycad](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/14486/499) plant and it has a minor infestation of [scale](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/8218/499).

- Provide good drainage for the plant so it doesn't sit in water. .The pot should have drainage holes
- Scale can be controlled with soap and water but it takes diligence and repeated applications so you can catch the juveniles after they hatch. See [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/5327/499) for more details

Comment: On a small plant like that, you can also try hand-picking.

Comment: Soap and water is not very effective from what I have experienced.  But following a wash recipe online, I rescued a fiscus from a major scale attack.  I used soap, water, and rubbing alcohol.  It penetrated the waxy coating I think.  Leaves need to be tested though.  The shiny surface of the ficus was unharmed, but a more supple leaf may get damaged.

Comment: Soap and water can have limited effectiveness if you do not repeat the applications.  But..rubbing alcohol does help if added to the mix